# Return list of all values that match criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, list

I am trying to help my boss set up an Excel sheet but I am not too familiar.

I am looking to list all values of a cell that match a criteria.

```
Sheet 1

    A    B
1  Adam  4
2  Dave  4
3  Steve 3
4  Ryan  4
```

What I want is to return a list of all names with values in column B that equal 4.

So the result would look like this:

```
     A       B
1 RESULTS   Adam
            Dave
            Ryan
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what about a pivot table? You can set name as row headers, set values as filter, then filter to `4`. You can find several good tutorials on pivot tables online.

Comment: You can just use a filter -- either the simple or advanced filter can accomplish that.

Answer (score 8):

A neat solution that I think may work for these scenarios:

```
=FILTER(A:A,B:B=D1,"") where D1 contains the number you want to filter by.
```

Comment: Worth noting FILTER function is only available to 365 subscribers not regular Excel users.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a pivot table, you can use an array formula.

I'm using `D4` to store the number you want to return (in this case names that match `4`)..but you can edit as necessary:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$4)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")`

Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down.

[image]

Comment: without CSE `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4)/(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4=4),ROW(1:1))),"")`

Comment: [@ScottCraner](https://media.giphy.com/media/nVXzt7FSJlX7W/giphy.gif) - that's really nifty, thanks for that!!

Comment: @Jeeped not bad though!! Congrats on winning the car, that's so crazy...especially since you had the better flush! I bet that was a crazy feeling. Kudos and thanks for all of your help again! :D

Comment: @Jeeped - D'oh, meant to type full house.  Haha, that's so crazy, I can't believe you kept your cool...way to go!!  :D

Comment: Can this be edited so that it returns only distinct values?

Comment: @akinuri probably? What have you tried, that would be a new question if you're making attempts and still can't crack it.

Comment: @BruceWayne I managed to get it working using this formula: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$25, MATCH(0, IF($A$2:$A$25=1, COUNTIF($I$1:$I1, $B$2:$B$25), ""), 0))`. I have two columns next to each other (A, B). Column A has `1` in some cells, and B has repeating values. I wanted to get distinct values from B that had their left cells set to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that a simple `INDEX` and `MATCH` function would be much simpler:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:B4,1,MATCH($F$1,B1:B4,0)),"")
```

[image: Excel print showing the formula and results]

Comment: The formula will break in case there is another value at the end that satisfies the condition. Long story short, it will have unwanted int values(numbers) along the way. Also, it will be great if you could post the actual code, not captured image.```=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:B5,1,MATCH($D$1,B2:B5,0)),"")```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=4),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the results to spill over in to other cells, you can use TEXTJOIN and a condition, which will create an in-the-cell listing of what you're looking for.

`=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, UNIQUE(IF(D1=B:B,A:A,"")))`

Where D1 would be the value of "4" or whatever you're looking for.

Which would give you a result of:

`Adam, Dave, Ryan`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).