# Return list of all values that match any of a few criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm new to this site so hope I'm doing this right!

I've made use of @BruceWayne array formula in the answer to the follow question: 
[Return list of all values that match criteria](https://superuser.com/q/1169289/957372)

My question is, can this formula be adjusted to consider any values in a list of multiple match criteria?  For example using this earlier question, I would want to put "4" in Cell D1 (as Bruce did) but also "3" in cell D2, which would return the list of all four names in the array starting cell F1.

I hope that's clear and many thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

[image]

*Write this Array Formula in Cell `D1`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and fill down.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$B,SMALL(IF(OR($B:$B=$A$9,$B:$B=$B$9),ROW($A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1,1),"")}
```

**Option 2:**

[image]

*Write this Array Formula in Cell `I2` finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`& fill down.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$G$7, SMALL(IF((INDEX($F$2:$G$7, , $G$11)<=$G$10)*(INDEX($F$2:$G$7, , $G$11)>=$G$9), MATCH(ROW($F$2:$G$7), ROW($F$2:$G$7)), ""), ROWS(I2:$I$2)), COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*