# Getting list of all values that match criteria from a timeseries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a timeseries that I would like to analyse. I would like to extract some data that matches certain criteria. However, I also need to ensure that formula looks at the latest data (i.e. the latest column added to a timeseries).

To extract a list of data that matches the criteria, I can use the answer provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1169289/return-list-of-all-values-that-match-criteria)

To ensure that excel can include the new columns in the formula, I can use `offset` function mentioned in this [answer](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/647755-select-range-column-based-criteria.html).

However, I am struggling to use both answers to create the formula I want.

Desired output:

```
Names   24/03/2019   25/03/2019     Criteria     Date                   
Name 1       A            A               A      25/03/2019              
Name 2       A            B
Name 3       B            A
Name 4       C            A
Name 5       A            A
```

In the example above, I would like the formula to change the list of names that have letter 'A' in today's column, from 3 names to 4 names, when today's column is added to the timeseries.

Comment: You have a label "Desired output", but that appears to be your input.  It isn't clear what the output should look like.  You also describe the data expanding, but it isn't clear from your image how the data would expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an 'OFFSET' function can be used here, it is a volatile function.  This means that it will recalculate every time something on the sheet changes even if it has no effect on the formula.  As an alternative I would propose using `INDEX` which is a non-volatile formula that only recalculates when something affecting it changes.

Lets assume your data starts in B2 (B2=Names).  Another assumption is going to be that no numbers can be in row 2 other than the dates and that the dates are stores in excel format and are not text.

Use the following formula in an empty cell where you want your list to appear and copy down.  I would go down as far as your list of names to cover off the possibility of all names being a valid choice:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$7)/(INDEX($C$3:$D$7,0,MATCH($F$3,$C$2:$D$2,0))=$E$3),ROW(A1))),"")
```

adjust the ranges to suit your needs.  Be mindful of what references need to be locked ($) and which ones need to be free to change.

[image: POC]